# Как удалить n-ое кол-во символов через m-ое кол-во строк?

Tags: delphi, строки

Ситуация довольно сложная, идей 0

в memo текст такого вида:

```
http://сайт1
http://сайт2
....
http://сайт95
http://сайт96u
http://сайт97o
http://сайт98h
...
http://сайт190g
http://сайт191hg
http://сайт192tf
....
http://сайт285gt
```

как вы заметили количество символов возрастает на 1 через каждые 95 строе, начиная с 95-ой. Символы всегда разные. Вопрос как их удалить?

Надеюсь что понятно описал проблему

Comment: По-моему, пора прекращать кормиться сниппетами из инета и прочитать какой-либо учебный курс. А то у вас всегда *идей 0*.

Answer (score 1):

вывести зависимость длинны строки от номера строчки, в цикле пройтись по строкам и обрезать их по нужной длине. Почитать учебник, функции SubString и все подобные, поискать в гугле "работа со строками Delphi" "работа с TMemo Delphi" и быть счастливым

Comment: Уж лучше установить Python и использовать срезы.